# Issue with the responsiveness

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with the responsiveness of my template. When I check the responsiveness online on websites, it looks perfect, everything works fine. When I check the responsiveness on my HTC one, it looks awful, it's not fully responsive.
I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` in the `<head>` of the template.

I don't know what I should do. Hope someone knows the answer.
Your answer would be highly appreciated !

Comment: To start with...don't do this `maximum-scale=1`. It's very poor user experience. Also, what does "looks awful" mean?. Please provide detail.

Comment: Check your media queries breaking points :)

Comment: Or event better, how about a link?

Comment: I can see only the center of the template. The rest can't be seen on my mobile. Also, the responsive menu doesn't work on my HTC. But  it appear when I check on online websites.

Comment: Works great on an iphone!

Comment: @Dominofoe Nice to hear it. Thank you.

Comment: If you're using chrome as browser, try to install an extension called "user agent switcher for chrome" that allows you to simulate mobile user agent like android, ipad, iphones etc...maybe it could help a bit for develop purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
1) Download from [here](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/download/Sizer,0301-5123.html) or just google it.
2) Check your HTCs screen resolution,
3) Adjust your browser window size to your mobile resolution and develop responsive design.
4) Debug.
5) Check how to use media [queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).